# ReplaySafeSplit contract on Mist v0.8.10

Tags: mist, ether, ethereum-classic

I'm trying to split my ETH/ETC from a presale wallet in Mist v0.8.10. I've followed the original Steemit post on running the split contract yet when I go to run the contract it doesn't show a field to input the number of coins I wish to split. I would obviously like to send a small amount first to ensure if all works as desired. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you post a bit more information please? What split contract exactly are you referring to? I would assume that the contract just splits all of the funds you send to it, so there's no need to input the value.

Comment: 0xAA1A6e3e6EF20068f7F8d8C835d2D22fd5116444

Comment: On the post from Steemit it showed an extra field which would allow you to specify the number of coins you want to split. I'm not prepared to split my entire balance without a test to make sure it works properly.

Comment: You don't need to. What client/interface are you using to send the transaction?

Comment: I'm using mist v0.8.10

Comment: A screenshot may help as well

Answer (score 2):

In **Ethereum Wallet**, on the contract interface page, there is a drop-down list under **Write To Contract**. Select the *Split* function, enter the two addresses that you wan to split to, then select the sender address under **Execute From** and input the amount that you want to split in the box under **Send Ether**. You can click the word **Ether** to select Finney, which will let you input the ammount to send in units of 1/1000 ETH.

EDIT:

It appears that for some reason this functionality is *only* available in the Ethereum Wallet application, and *not* in the full Mist browser. Please install Ethereum Wallet from here: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases

Comment: That's exactly what the steemit post showed... what I'm saying is that the Send Ether field doesn't appear. There is no option to send a portion of the Eth I have in "Main Account". It will only let me Execute without specifying the amount. When I hit Execute it takes me to the next screen and makes it seems as though the Contract will run correctly but without specifying a number of ETH/ETC to split. Any ideas from there? Have I left something out of the json interface when writing the contract?

Comment: I still see the send ETH field, in mist 0.8.10. If you post a screenshot, maybe I can see what's wrong

Comment: This is embarassing... I can't figure out how to paste a screenshot here bud.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow

Comment: You, sir, are a legend. Thank you for your help. I got the wallet application and all seems to work.