# Cannot see the 'amount' field for no replay contract in Mist wallet v0.9.0

Tags: mist, wallets, contract-invocation

I have followed the instructions on these reference pages:
https://steemit.com/ethereum/@pauls/ethereum-fork-step-by-step-guide-to-safely-splitting-your-eth-etc

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/07/26/onward_from_the_hard_fork/

I have added ('+ WATCH CONTRACT' button) for both contracts to my Ethereum Mist wallet v0.9.0 but I do not see the expected 'Send ' field for either contract. Any help or advise would be appreciated.

[image: screencapture]

Screen capture from this other [reference question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21589/replaysafesplit-contract-on-mist-v0-8-10/) but I have the identical problem and I cannot see from that post what the resolution was either if the user was using the wallet already but says using the wallet was the solution! (Sorry in advance if I missed something very obvious, I am just not able to comment on existing answers till my reputation reaches 50 unfortunately).